# In eclipse, Tomcat 6 using javax.servlet-api 3.0.1 with 'provided' scope

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, spring-mvc, tomcat

I am developing Spring mvc application. I am using eclipse.

I was using Tomcat 7 and below pom entry for servlet

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

And facet version 3.0

```
<installed facet="jst.web" version="3.0"/>
```

Due some reason, I have to use Tomcat 6.
After some search, I found that Tomcat 6 uses javax-servlet 2.5 version.

So, I changed my pom entry to

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

And facet version to 2.5

```
<installed facet="jst.web" version="2.5"/>
```

I resolved some compilation errors and found that @WebFilter is not supported by this. So, I removed @WebFilter and made entry of my filter in web.xml.

My project got deployed on Tomcat 6.

Out of curiosity to use @WebFilter with Tomcat 6, I changed my pom entry to use `3.0.1` javax.servlet with scope as `provided` and then tried to use @WebFilter and it worked.

Can any one please help me to understand how it is happening. As scope of javax.servlet is provided and I am using Tomcat 6. From where it is getting this version of javax.servlet?

Thanks

Comment: How about running `mvn dependency:tree`?  This will reveal if any other dependency is including this.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I am using eclipse plugin. In eclipse, when I go to Navigate -> Open Type and then search for WebFilter, it is pointing to javax-servlet-api-3.0.1.jar present in maven repository.

Comment: Open `pom.xml` and click on `Dependency graph` - look for `servlet-api` related dependencies.

Comment: In Dependency Hierarchy, it is showing `javax.servlet-api : 3.0.1 [provided]`, as I have used 1st pom entry mentioned in my question with `apache-tomcat-6.0.41`.

Answer (score 0):

Simple servlet containers such as Apache Tomcat come with this API (look for servlet-api.jar).

Comment: Thanks for replying. I have included server libraries in my build path. But that servlet-api.jar does not support @WebFilter (As I am using `apache-tomcat-6.0.41`)